# In how many ways can I combine x elements

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

In how many ways can I combine x elements and why?
Example: If I have 6 elements, indicating each element with a number, some possible cases could be: $1,2,3/\,1,4,3/\, 1,2,5,6/\, ...$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for,

$xC_0+xC_1+\dots+xC_x=2^x$

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain further please?

Comment: $nC_r$ counts the number of ways to choose $r$ elements from $n$ elements. We simply sum over $r$ which gives the number ways of size 1,size 2, subsets etc. The sum value follows from the Binomial Theorem, which gives an expansion for $(a+b)^n$ . If we set $a=b=1$ the result follows.